# Embed code html to play rtmp stream with additional attributes?

Tags: html, stream, rtmp, http-live-streaming

does any one know the way to play, rtmp stream with attributes embded on a website?

Also if i have:

> rtmp://$OPT:rtmp-raw=rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx/live?idp=4050/rer_835660 playpath=rofl swfUrl=http://www.somewww.com/tv/swf/player.swf?file=redtofile&autostart=true&/2/3 live=1 pageUrl=http://www.somewww.com/tv/get_file.php

the real rtmp link is:

> rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx/live?idp=4050/rer_835660/rofl

some of rtmp will play if there is no token for swf player protection. That is why i need swfUrl and pageUrl added and sometimes Decrypt option.

Is it even possible? I know that vlc have some issues with playing such as url's.

//edit:
I know that my link does play in SimpleTV but i have to get it every time it changes. I have written php script so it fetches actual link for me as soon as I open my webpage. So i know its correct.

Just need to find way to play it, with anything, except SimpleTV.
Preferably Embed code for website, normal rtmp links i play via vlc plugin, but it does not support such as long rtmp links, example shown above. I might be wrong? That might be me could phase or construct correctly rtmp link.

Comment: Could you explain more you question ? Where do you want to use these parameters ? Do you want only to use vlc to play your stream ?

Comment: Hi @akmozo, i just want to play those links, on pc, android, ios. Prefferably via website, not via simpletv because them links are dynamic, some of them are changing. That is why i needed it embed. Rtmp://$opt-rtmp-raw=rtmp://linktostream/ playPath=linktoplaypath links looks more like this, and not do not have to be vlc to play them files.